# Details view (Package update and backup) to small

Tags: gnome, gui

I've installed a new ubuntu 16.04.
After this I mentioned that my detail views (for updates screen) are too   small (only one row).

[image: Here is the example for the one line (the black line)]

How can I fix it, or how did this problem come up?

Thanks,
Sebastian